# Sort 2 Columns + Adj Column by matching Numbers

Tags: excel

I have a long list of ID number in Column C with important information in Column D-Q.

I need to sort it accordingly to a specific set of ID numbers in Column B along with the matching  information in Col D-Q, like this:

I have this:

```
B     C     D      E . . . 
123   234   male   12
234   345   female 13
345   555   male   12
444   123   male   11
```

I need this:

```
B    C      D      E . . . 
123  123    male   11 
234  234    male   12
345  345    female 13
444  N/A     N/A   N/A
```

Essentially, I need the information from C (and the adjacent info) to match with B or get *sorted* by the ID numbers in B.  The file is huge and I  just need to pull/sort it just by a specific set of ID numbers.

Thank you!

EDIT:I tried to use as suggested, the following in a new column. However, I receive the #N/A and #REF error.

```
=Index(D:Q,Match(B:B, C:C,0) 
Provides error: #N/A and #REF!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the matching data from C-Q using `index(array, match())`. Just make the `match()` on B and C.